# JSX condition that does not work with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dictionary

I just started React and I'm facing a problem: when I run this piece of code, nothing is displayed.

```js
const plantList = {
    name: 'monstera',
    category: 'classique',
    id: '1ed',
    isBestSale: true
};

function Notes(){
    plantList.map((plant) => (
    <li key={ plant.id }>
        {plant.isBestSale ? <span></span> : <span></span>}
    </li>
))}

export default Notes
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you are trying to map through an object. map has to be used on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plantList` is an object, you probably want to put it in an array if you want to put multiple plants in it and have the ability to map over it.

```
const plantList = [{
  name: 'monstera',
  category: 'classique',
  id: '1ed',
  isBestSale: true
}];
```

You are not returning a value from your function component.

```
function Notes(){
return (
    <>
      {plantList.map((p) => (p.isBestSale ? <span></span> : <span></span>))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I made a code-in to illustrate my situation : it still doesn't work : https://codepen.io/clement-gaudiniere/pen/poaRopy

Comment: @ClémentGaudinière you are not returning a value from your component (updated the answer)

Comment: @ClémentGaudinière glad I could help, happens to everyone 

Answer (score 1):

playlist is an object. But the object is not iterable in js. if you want to iterate you need to make it an array look like as

```
const plantList = [{
     name: 'monstera',
     category: 'classique',
     id: '1ed',
     isBestSale: true
 }];
```

you need to return anything from class/functional component to display

```
function Notes(){
     return (
     <>
       {plantList.map((p) => (p.isBestSale ? <span></span> : <span> 
    </span>))}
   </>
)}
```

export default Notes